# Where is the location for network configuration files in Kali Linux, like "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/"?

Tags: kali-linux, network-interface

I'm using Kali Linux 6.0.0-kali5-amd64, and I was watching a tutorial on how to configure networks, but since they were using Fedora, they always go to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens*`.

So I'm wondering where the configuration files Kali Linux are located. People say it's in `/etc/network/interfaces`, but I haven't seen it true because it was empty. I'm a new Linux user, so I don't understand where I'm going wrong.